# Haskell--List appending using Guards

Tags: list, haskell

I am working on a simulation for a checkers game currently.  I have developed a function called onemove:

```
    onemove :: (Int,[Char],[[Char]],(Int,Int)) -> (Int,[Char],[[Char]])
```

This function takes a tuple as input and returns a tuple of modified information.  I have defined the input variables as follows:

```
    onemove     (a,b,c,(d,e))
```

Where c is a list of chars, ie, captured pieces.  I am currently utilizing guards and a where clause to complete the move to be made from 'd' to 'e'.  How do I append an element to the list b within the where clause, if even possible?  My sample code is as follows:

```
    onemove :: (Int,[Char],[[Char]],(Int,Int)) -> (Int,[Char],[[Char]])

    onemove     (a,b,c,(d,e)) 
        | e <= 0 =(a-30,b,c)
        | (posFrom == 'r') && (posTo == '-') && ( leftOrRight == 9) = (a-15,b,removeWRightMan)
        | otherwise = (10000,b,c)
        where posFrom = getPos d c
              rightWGuy = d+4
              b ++ rightWGuy
              removeWRightMan = setPos rightWGuy sFPosTo '-'
```

The value rightWGuy is however an Int and I am attempting to pass it to a [char]..Does this need to be converted to a char before attepting to append to the list b?  Thanks

Comment: You can do ``b ++ [(intToDigit rightWGuy)]`` (first you have to import the function from ``Data.Char``) to achieve the desired effect. But I am not sure that this little change will help because you do not utilise the result of the concatenation and therefore render it moot.

Comment: I attempt to use the result of b++ within the `(a-15,b,removeWRightMan)`..I would like the returned list of chars to contain the new element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to just convert `rightWGuy` to a `[Char]` you could do:

```
import Data.Char (intToDigit)

-- some other things
b ++ [(intToDigit rightWGuy)]
```

**Note that `intToDigit` only works for input in range `[0..15]`!**

Alternatively, to simplify you can also just use `show`. Another advantage of `show` is that it supports any number, not only 0 to 15.

```
b ++ (show rightWGuy)
```

With the clarification of your comment, you probably want to so this:

```
onemove :: (Int,[Char],[[Char]],(Int,Int)) -> (Int,[Char],[[Char]])

onemove     (a,b,c,(d,e)) 
  | e <= 0 =(a-30,b,c)
  | (posFrom == 'r') && (posTo == '-') && ( leftOrRight == 9) = (a-15,x,removeWRightMan) -- instead of b use x now
  | otherwise = (10000,b,c)
    where 
       posFrom = getPos d c
       rightWGuy = d+4
       x = b ++ (show rightWGuy) -- x is now b ++ rightWGuy
       removeWRightMan = setPos rightWGuy sFPosTo '-'
```

Because Haskell has no side effects, just doing `b ++ [(intToDigit rightWGuy)]` will **not** change `b`, it will yield a new list which is the result of the concatenation. This result we now store in `x`, which we will use in our new tuple as you wish to do.

Comment: The assignment of the list to a new variable 'x' makes sense.  With intToDigit however, any digit above 15 yields and error.  Is there by chance a more generalizable int to Char converter? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Dev Updated to use ``show`` instead of ``intToDigit``, should work now!

Comment: show will return type **String** rather than **Char**.  Looking through the documentation again.

Comment: @Dev I am aware of that, but as ``[(intToDigit rightWGuy)]`` is of type ``[Char]``, so is ``(show rightWGuy)``. What is your problem?

Comment: In ghci: ``"123" ++ [(intToDigit 3)] == "123" ++ (show 3)`` evaluates to ``True``.

Comment: I receive an error as the return is expecting a char and show is returning a string.  Although I just noticed in Haskell `String` is alias for `[char]`..Specifically my error states: Couldn't match type `[Char]` with `Char`------
    Expected type: `Char`------
      Actual type: `String`

Comment: [chat discussion](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59029/discussion-between-threefx-and-dev)